# Uploading and Storing videos online using PHP and ffmpeg

Tags: php, video, video-streaming

I have a website that allows users to upload videos to it,
After they upload videos, I would like to be able to display them using a flash player.

One flash player i know is flowplayer, althrough if anyone knows a better one I will be happy to know.

In any case, as I understood from a brief google search, there are no players that can play .avi/.mpeg files, but they can only play .flv files.

I began searching for ways to convert my user's avi's/mpeg's and found that I can use ffmpeg  to convert the video to .flv using system().

Is this the best solution for me? I feel like ffmpeg takes a lot of CPU and once I have enough users the server will crash..

Thanks!

Comment: Am I using the best solution? converting using php's system() and using ffmpeg

Comment: No, this is definitely not the best solution.

Comment: Do you mind sharing what is the best solution in your opinion?

Comment: You're right, only certain formats will play in flash players. You're also right that converting a video takes a lot of resources. This is more a problem of server infrastructure than which code to use for doing the encoding.

Comment: is there a better way to convert the videos? is there a better player that can play avi/mpeg files?

Comment: Not really. Flash player can only handle a limited selection of codecs. If you serve different avi/mpeg formats to be played by, say, the client's native Windows Media Player component, the *client* will need to have the appropriate codecs installed. That's not going to work well. The server *will* have to convert the uploaded videos to some common format (H.264 is everybody's favorite right now), and that simply takes a lot of resources, full stop. You'll probably need a dedicated server or ten working through a queue of uploaded videos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just an outline

<sup>(Note: i don't own nor wrote a PHP video sharing site, so treat these like tips)</sup>

- Set up your web server and PHP to be capable of accepting large files via HTTP
- Let users upload their videos via a web interface
- Upon successful upload add uploaded video to a queue
- Set up a fully server side script that handles video processing (No PHP)
- Run a cron job on this queue when your server is able to crunch uploaded videos
- Notify users when videos are done

Hope it helps in some way.